# Why Xcode keeps changing the storyboard defenitions

Tags: ios, xcode

Since i have `Xcode6` my life became a nightmare .
I just can't understand the constrains and storyboard issues, and i would like to get a little help, i made a lots of efforts, but things just dont seems to work.

First, there is a button says `w Any h Any` , in which you can choose your screen size. I set it to `fit all iPhones in portrait` . Why `Xcode` change it back to `Any` every time i open it again ?
Why he does not keep it in this configuration?

Second, i would like to try and understand this thing, is there a difference, when i work on `all iPhones` or when i work on `Any` ? so for example, if i set some label and set its constrains in the mode of `Any`, will it looks different if i do the same in mode `all iPhones` ?

In other words ,please correct me if i am wrong with this : If i set a label to be centered in the iPhones mode , than its vertical distance constrain from the top is **x** ,and the storyboard height is **y** , so for any iPhone with screen height of **y*a** , that distance will becomes **x*a** ? is that correct ?

Comment: I dont have,the question is not about specific view , its out understanding the principles, you can assume a label in the screen. btw, can you help me understand my first and second issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to a new feature of Xcode 6 called "Size classes", where you can define different constraints/subviews for different *device classes*.

You cannot define the *iPhone Portrait size class* unless you also define the base *any size class*, that's why it keeps changing back.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) for more explanations on the official Apple Documentation.

The answer to your second question is no, they don't change: with *size classes* you can enable/disable/change constraints depending on the *size class*, but the basic function of the constraint will be the same on all size classes (e.g., the center in superview constraint will always center using the current superview bounds).

Comment: thanks very much , i am not sure i understand what you said.I have read the Apple docs, 1 . when you set the size classes, it will always make it to be "Any" ? i once disabled it, and it DELETED ALL MY CONSTRAINS! 2. something here, is still not logic. if you set it to Any, than the storyboard is 600x600 , that means ,the aspect ratio is 1:1 . for every view you put in, all distances will be calculated for 1:1 , so , of course it should looks different for device with 2:3 ??  , in other words, how my example with x*a can be explained, according to this ?

Comment: The size of the views on the Storyboard is just representative. By default View Controllers' Views will take the size of the device window (or more specifically, that of their parent view). Constraints don't calculate distances based on a precalculated aspect ratio. Constraints relate attributes between each other and to metrics that you manually define. The "center" constraint just defines: "center this view in its superview".

Comment: I think it's a good idea to re-read the [AutoLayout introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html), and then reading the [Size class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/ChangeViewPosition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH9-SW1) document again. It's all explained there.

Comment: Also, it's only normal that disabling "Size classes" deletes all your constraints, as I don't see a way Xcode can translate size-specific constraint data to the regular old model of specifying constraints. If your app is not complicated, I suggest you disable Size classes. You can still support different device sizes on the old universal mode as well, and it's simpler to understand when starting out with AutoLayout.

Comment: ok thanks a lot,  so you said the answer to my second question is "yes" , that means there is a difference between storyboard set to "any" , and to iPhones, but now you say its the same ? actually i read this document 2 times, i just can't understand its principles.

Comment: wait, so you say, if i disable the size classes, i will be back to the old mode again, where i just put things on storyboard and it all fits to any device like magic ??

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant to say the answer is No. The constraint will work the same on all sizes. Disabling size classes, it won't fit "to any device like magic", you still need to set constraints so your subviews, labels, etc., are located and sized as you want them to be. But it'll be simpler doing that, yes.

Comment: well i am not sure what to do now. our app is complicated, but not in the UI aspect. we used to take the story board, put everything inside, and it just fits all iPads, now ,with xcode6, and the iPhones, everything messed up. what was different when i used xcode5, and put everything on storyboard and it fits all iPads ?